# Find expressions equal to a given number using 15 integers with 4 operators

Tags: c++, performance

For example, given 15 integers

```
70, 75, 32, 4, 64, 98, 73, 52, 36, 88, 96, 58, 79, 39, 75
```

How can we obtain is 72?

4 operators can be used for the 15 integers to get the equation to the answer of 72, which are `+ - * /`. Divison is only allowed where there is no remainder.
A few answers will be

- `4+32+36+39+52-58-64-70+73+75/75-79-88+96+98`
- `4+32+36-39-52+58*64+70+73*75+75+79+88-96*98`
- `4+32*36*39/52-58+64-70+73*75-75*79-88-96-98`
- `4+32*36*39/52-98+64-70+73*75-75*79-88-96-58`

#### Rules

- `5+1-3` and `5-3+1` are 2 different answers.
- No duplicated answer.
- All 15 integers must be used in the equation in any order.

Time given is 200 seconds.

What is the "best" strategy or optimization can be used to obtain as many expressions as possible in the allotted time?  The brute-force complexity is (15!*4<sup>14</sup>), which is approximately 3.5 × 10<sup>20</sup>.

The code below is the code written by me and it is partially optimized by me, it just able to compute 1.0e9 combinations in 200s.
Performance analysis shows that `prev_num_pos()` used 31% of computation time and
`nextoptgroup()` used 15% of computation time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define PROBLEMSIZE 15
#define PRINTTOSCREEN false
#define OPERATIONUSED 3

int numgroup[PROBLEMSIZE]; //numbers array
int optgroup[PROBLEMSIZE - 1]; //operations array
int theanswer; //the target answer
int size=PROBLEMSIZE;
ofstream output("solution.txt", ios::app);

bool nextoptgroup(){ //true = success next-ed, false = tried all combinations
    for (int i = PROBLEMSIZE - 2; i >= 0; i--){ //bruteforce type
        if (optgroup[i] < OPERATIONUSED){ //increase itself if possible
            optgroup[i] += 1;
            break;
        }
        else { //optgroup[i] == 3
            optgroup[i] = 0;  //reset itself to 0 and continue to increase its parent
        }
        if (i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

char symbols(int s){
    switch (s){
    case 0:
        return '+';
    case 1:
        return '-';
    case 2:
        return '*';
    case 3:
        return '/';
    default:
        return '$';
    }
}

void print_out(int status =0){ //0 = do not print to file, 1 = correct answer, print to file
    if (PRINTTOSCREEN) cout << numgroup[0];
    if (status==1) output << numgroup[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEMSIZE-1; i++){
        if (PRINTTOSCREEN)  cout << symbols(optgroup[i]) << numgroup[i + 1];
        if (status == 1) output << symbols(optgroup[i]) << numgroup[i + 1];
    }
}

//only will use for * / , priortized
int prev_num_pos(int opt[], int pos){ //check for prev non -1 position, return num pos
    for (int i = pos - 1; i >= 0; i--){ //used for num position
        if (opt[i] != -1) return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void debug_print(int num[],int opt[]){
    cout << num[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEMSIZE - 1; i++){
        if (opt[i]!=-1) cout << symbols(opt[i]) << num[i + 1];
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}

int main(){
    ifstream input("problems.txt");
    if (input.is_open() == false) return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEMSIZE; i++) { //get problems
        input >> numgroup[i];
    }
    input >> theanswer; //get answer
    input.close();
    cout << "Numbers given: "<< numgroup[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < PROBLEMSIZE; i++) { //show problems
        cout << ", " << numgroup[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "The answer needed: " << theanswer << endl << endl;
    if (PRINTTOSCREEN) system("PAUSE");
    for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEMSIZE - 1; i++) { //initialize optgroup
        optgroup[i] = 0;
    }

    sort(numgroup, numgroup + PROBLEMSIZE);//sort the problems

    

    do { //iterate every combinations
        //calculate the answer based on numgroup and optgroup
        //need give priority to * / % left to right otherwise
        do { //for each combination of number need to go through each operation combination
            //create a copy for calculation, both num n opt
            int cnumgroup[PROBLEMSIZE];
            int coptgroup[PROBLEMSIZE];
            size = PROBLEMSIZE;
            for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEMSIZE; i++){
                cnumgroup[i] = numgroup[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < PROBLEMSIZE; i++){
                coptgroup[i] = optgroup[i];
            }
            //bool to skip this undivisible loop
            bool cont = false;
            //give priority
            for (int it = 0; it < PROBLEMSIZE - 1; ++it) { //it = position of opt
                int prev_pos = -1;
                if (coptgroup[it] == 2 || coptgroup[it] == 3){ // !goodforpermfornace
                    prev_pos = prev_num_pos(coptgroup, it);
                }
                else continue;
                if (coptgroup[it] == 2){ //for multiplier*
                    cnumgroup[prev_pos] = cnumgroup[prev_pos] * cnumgroup[it + 1];
                    coptgroup[it] = -1; //set operator to used
                    //debug_print(cnumgroup, coptgroup); //!debug!
                }
                else if (coptgroup[it] == 3) { //for division/
                    if (cnumgroup[prev_pos] % cnumgroup[it + 1] != 0){ //have remainder, undivisible
                        cont = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        cnumgroup[prev_pos] = cnumgroup[prev_pos] / cnumgroup[it + 1];
                        coptgroup[it] = -1; //set operator to used
                        //debug_print(cnumgroup, coptgroup); //!debug!
                    }
                }
            }
            if (cont) continue;
            //do remaining add and subtract
            for (int it = 0; it < PROBLEMSIZE - 1; ++it) {
                if (coptgroup[it] == -1) continue; // !goodforpermfornace
                if (coptgroup[it] == 0){ // for addition+
                    cnumgroup[0] = cnumgroup[0] + cnumgroup[it + 1]; //add to the first number
                    coptgroup[it] = -1; //set operator to used
                    //debug_print(cnumgroup, coptgroup); //!debug!
                }
                else if (coptgroup[it] == 1) { //for subtraction-
                    cnumgroup[0] = cnumgroup[0] - cnumgroup[it + 1]; //subtract the first number
                    coptgroup[it] = -1; //set operator to used
                    //debug_print(cnumgroup, coptgroup); //!debug!
                }
                else if (coptgroup[it]!=-1) { //!performance!
                    if (PRINTTOSCREEN)  cout << "ERROR FOUND!! CODE:ADDSUBLOOPBUTNOT\n";
                }
            }
            //finished all the calculation, check the answer
            if (cnumgroup[0] == theanswer){
                //answer found
                //print it out
                print_out(1);
                output << endl;
                if (PRINTTOSCREEN)  cout << "\tCorrect\n"; //!performance!
            }
            else { // !BAD!performance!
                if (size > 1){
                    if (PRINTTOSCREEN)  cout << "ERROR FOUND!! CODE:CNUMGROUPSIZEisNOT1\n";
                }
                else {
                    print_out();
                    if (PRINTTOSCREEN)  cout << "\tWrong\n";
                }
            }
        } while (nextoptgroup());
    } while (next_permutation(numgroup, numgroup + PROBLEMSIZE));

    output.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd sort the numbers and employ a tree to memoize previous operations like in a transaction database. I'd also memoize and check for repeated operations (they would be invalidated) At the end, I'd filter the valid leafs for 70. Assuming they can all divide each other and none are unique, you have a worst case of 120 operations (not instructions) to run, and this can easily be done on one pass after trivial sorting. Just an algorithmic tip.

Comment: Also, don't be afraid of labelled loops. Your `cont = true; break;` could be simplified to `continue loop;`, adding a `loop:` before your inner `do ... while`, and removing the `if (cont) continue;` statement.

Comment: I'm not a frequent C++ user, but I've used those a few times even in JS. It's much simpler conceptually IMO, and it's easier to optimize (I don't think g++ is quite *that* intelligent yet, but who knows).

Comment: @IsiahMeadows Since performance is the main priority here, labelled loop is fine if it can improve performance. But is it the loop checking is the bottleneck here?

Comment: @IsiahMeadows Your tree method seems interesting, if can be implemented like what you said, it is very possible that the calculation can be completed within given time. But I have a hard time to imagine the pseudo code for this method, further reference or explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: The labelled loop won't make much of a difference unless this is called millions of times in a super tight loop, and by that point, you might as well dive into assembly, but it's just cleaner visually.

Comment: As for my tree idea: you start at the top level, with one root tree node. From there, with your first and second four numbers, perform each operation on it, and store the arguments - an `unordered_set<long>` would work, with `((long) int1 << 32) & int2` for your values in it. If the result is valid (i.e. divisible or not divided), add the operation's result to the tree node. Then, for each child node, you check if it's in the set, and if it doesn't exist, do the same as above, but with the two numbers being the next four numbers and their respective parent values.

Comment: At the end of the traversal (i.e. last two numbers are calculated), you grab all the values at the last traversal (you can special case the last traversal if you want to), filter out those that aren't 72, and there's your result.

Comment: And where I said earlier that it was 120 operations worst case, assuming none of them were unique, I should've said *480* (4 times that) operations worst case, and that it assumes *all* are unique. My bad.

Comment: Regardless of final algorithm it should be possible to multithread efficiently, either by OS threads or a compute language (OpenCL/CUDA). OpenMP might also be an option.

Comment: @IsiahMeadows Actually I failed to get the 480 operations you mentioned. I'm not really fully understand you method. But one thing that I feel this method lack is the * / have higher priority than - + when calculating the answer. If this tree method can tolerate the * / priority problem, can you draw the simplified tree structure into a picture?
Thanks for your effort and time used for trying to solve this question.

Comment: @B.Liew I may have been wrong with 480, but I got it from 4 * (1 + 2 + ... + 15), one for each possible branch of the largest tree. And yes, my method originally lacked that ability, but I've revised it some. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/isiahmeadows/17fd47027ca42d567b6ee8bb91fd5f67) for more details. It also includes a JS version where I normally think a little more functionally. It's highly recursive, but that should never be a problem in practice.

Comment: It might have compiler errors (I didn't test it), but I can make it an answer later if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of looking at it is, rather than rearranging the **numbers**, just rearrange the **symbols**. For example, with your fifteen numbers you  have 14 symbols between them, with any of 4 values: - + / *

Since each location is independent of each other, you are actually describing a binary number, with 2 bits per symbol location, for a total of 28 bits (=268,435,456)

Looked at it from this point of view, you just count from 0 to 268435456 and use each pair of bits in sequence to determine whether you use a +, -, / or * at that point. Here's some code that does that:

```
int a[]={4, 32, 36, 39, 52, 58, 64, 70, 73, 75, 75, 79, 88, 96, 98};
int aTot=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
long i=0, bitMask=1, sum=0, count=0, limit=268435456;
for (long bits=0;bits<limit;++bits)
{
  bitMask=bits;
  sum=a[0];
  for (i=1;i<aTot;++i)
  {
    switch (bitMask & 0x3 )
    {
      case 0:
        sum-=a[i];
        break;
      case 1:
        sum+=a[i];
        break;
      case 2:
        sum*=a[i];
        break;
      case 3:
        if ( ( sum % a[i] ) != 0 )
        {
          sum=-1;
          i=9999;
          break;
        }
        sum/=a[i];
        break;
    }
    bitMask>>=2;
  }
  if (sum==72)
  {
    bitMask=bits;
    std::cout << count++ << ": " << a[0];
    for (i=1;i<aTot;++i)
    {
      switch (bitMask & 0x3 )
      {
        case 0:
          std::cout << " - ";
          break;
        case 1:
          std::cout << " + ";
          break;
        case 2:
          std::cout << " * ";
          break;
        case 3:
          std::cout << " / ";
          break;
      }
      std::cout << a[i];
      bitMask>>=2;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

We massage the bits to get our sum, and if it matches 72, we just repeat the process to print out the formula.

Note the test for division - if the modulo fails, then it won't divide evenly, so we give up and break out of the loop.

Using this, I got 157 answers in about 11 seconds - which gives you another 189 seconds to permute the numbers and run it again (check out [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) for how to speed that up). Or you could take those 157 answers and rearrange them, letting you skip some math (and gain some speed).

In any case, hopefully this will give you a starting point to do the calcs...

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but the * and & do have higher priority than - +, which makes it more complicated.
As an example, 5+3*4 is actually 18 and not 32.
If you take care of the * / priority, will your idea still work?

Comment: Yes - you'd just have to do two passes - one to calculate the * / terms and another to calculate the remaining - + terms. There would be more bookkeeping as well (temporary values), but since the binary number bits represents the symbol between values, you would still end up trying every possible symbol for a given sequence of numbers.

Comment: You bitMask method is actually very fast compare to the array's element by element increment method. Can you give an idea that can do the bookkeeping work in an optimized way?

Comment: Especially when there are consecutive `* /` in a sequence, like `1+a*b/c+2` , which it must do `a*b=z` first then only `z/c=y`, lastly replace the `+a*b/c` into `+y` so that it becomes `1+y+2`.

Answer (score 2):

### Namespaces

[`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1014587). Short code is not a requirement in C++, clear code is preferred.

### System

[`system("PAUSE");` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24776380/1014587). `cin.get()` halts the program waiting for user input in a more standardized and portable-friendly way.

### Return

`return 0;` is a legacy from C. In C++, it's no longer required to write this manually. The compiler will take care of returning 'normal' if no errors were thrown or other returns (like `-1`) are encountered.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bad practices which I have done in the code given above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce the same output, but do the * / calcs first, you need to store the intermediate values in a stack or array:

```
int a[]={4, 32, 36, 39, 52, 58, 64, 70, 73, 75, 75, 79, 88, 96, 98};
const int aTot=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
long i=0, bitMask=1, sum=0, limit=268435456;
long stack[aTot], sI=0;
for (long bits=0;bits<limit;++bits)
{
  bitMask=bits;
  stack[0]=a[0];
  sI=1;
  for (i=1;i<aTot;++i)
  {
    switch (bitMask & 0x3 )
    {
      case 0:
        stack[sI++]=-a[i];
        break;
      case 1:
        stack[sI++]=a[i];
        break;
      case 2:
        stack[sI-1]*=a[i];
        break;
      case 3:
        if ( ( stack[sI-1] % a[i] ) != 0 )
        {
          sI=0;
          i=9999;
          break;
        }
        stack[sI-1]/=a[i];
        break;
    }
    bitMask>>=2;
  }
  sum=0;
  for (i=0;i<sI;++i)
    sum+=stack[i];
  if (sum==72)
  {
    bitMask=bits;
    std::cout << a[0];
    for (i=1;i<aTot;++i)
    {
      switch (bitMask & 0x3 )
      {
        case 0:
          std::cout << " - ";
          break;
        case 1:
          std::cout << " + ";
          break;
        case 2:
          std::cout << " * ";
          break;
        case 3:
          std::cout << " / ";
          break;
      }
      std::cout << a[i];
      bitMask>>=2;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

The code is vary similar to the previous code; however, instead of calculating the sum right away, we store results in an array called stack. If it's a +- term, we make it a new stack item; if it's */ we combine it with the latest stack item instead, giving a new value.

Once we're done, the stack has all the terms, but the */ ones have been combined - so now we just need to add them all, and see if they match 72.

This code will take one sequence of a[] and try all possible formulas for it - then, you can just permute the a[] array and rerun it to generate as many as possible. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for currently! But there is a lot of formulas you missed. The possible formulas not only can do `a*b-c*d+e` , it can even be `a*b-c*d*e` or `a+b/c*d*e`. Which the stacks of * / can be more than 2 numbers in it.

Comment: Step through the code and you'll see it handles multiple */ terms in a row, combining them...

Comment: Oh my mistake, it did.. After it gets an answer, then I can permute it and get other same answer with different order (the order of each * / sets will still permute inside their own sets). But actually the `a*b-c*d` and `a*c-b*d`is different, how do I get the second answer without permute all 15!  which will get duplicated answers and also not efficient.

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem - aside from 75, there are no identical numbers, so most of the permutations should be fine. Since you only have 200 secs, I doubt you'll be able to get through many, anyways.

Comment: And if you want to permutate the answer you already have, just remember operator precedence, so a X b can be rearranged to b X a, but a/b can't become b/a - group the terms you can't rearrange into groups, and permutate that. In fact, if you took each group and make it a string, you could permutate the array of strings, and just print them out, w/o any more calculations...

Comment: If the question size changed to only 5 numbers for a[] , it wouldn't get all possible formula. Because given than A B C D E, this method will not do A * E - B * C -D , which the position of E is totally different and there is a lot more combination for it, if i use the combinatorics method to get 5C2 - 3C2 - Z , which Z can be A to E. 5C2 means choose 2 numbers out of 5 then either multiply it or divide, then 3C2 is because after 5C2 there is only 3 numbers left to choose. If using this combinatorics way, for cases of 5C2 get AD , 3C2 get BC, then 5C2 get BC, 3C2 get AD.

Comment: Which they might get each others past combinations. Then this combinatorics method i mentioned that can get all possible formula will not works well because there will be duplicated answers.

Comment: You mentioned originally that you have 200 seconds to get as many answers as you can from about 10^20 possibilities. You won't get them all, so I'd concentrate on getting the ones you can as fast as possible. If you are worried about duplicates, you can always store answers in a dictionary, and check for duplicates as you add them.

Comment: Ya it is not possible to print out all the possible formula when there is 15! . But the size is actually not constant, it will be changed to something smaller, like 5! . Then it will not get all possible combinations even it is very small. Storing every printed formulas in a dictionary and checking the whole dictionary every time is way too slow..